# Insertion sort doesn't sort

Tags: python, algorithm, insertion-sort

I have attempted to create an insertion sort in python, however the list returned is not sorted. What is the problem with my code?

Argument given: [3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 8, 7, 9, 6]

Result: 2
1
3
6
4
7
5
8
9

Python code:

```
def insertion_sort(mylist):
    sorted_list = []
    for i in mylist:
        posfound = 0 #defaults to 0
        for j in range(len(sorted_list)):
            if sorted_list[j] > i:
                sorted_list.insert(j-1, i) #put the number in before element 'j'
                posfound = 1 #if you found the correct position in the list set to 1
                break
        if posfound == 0: #if you can't find a place in the list
            sorted_list.insert(len(sorted_list), i) #put number at the end of the list
    return sorted_list
```

Comment: If you're posting Python code, please make sure that your indentation is correctly copied. Badly indented Python code is nonsense.

Comment: `sorted_list.insert(len(sorted_list), i)` could be advantageously replaced by `sorted_list.append(i)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change `sorted_list.insert(j-1, i)` to be  `sorted_list.insert(j, i)` to insert before position `j`.

`insert(j-1, ..)` will insert before the *previous* element, and in the case where `j=0` it'll wrap around and insert before the last element.

The [Python data structures tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#data-structures) may be useful.

Answer (score 2):

As Efferalgan & tzaman have mentioned your core problem is due to an off-by-one error. To catch these sorts of errors it's useful to print `i`, `j` and `sorted_list` on each loop iteration to make sure they contain what you think they contain.

Here are a few versions of your algorithm. First, a repaired version of your code that fixes the off-by-one error; it also implements Efferalgan's suggestion of using `.append` if an insertion position isn't found.

```
def insertion_sort(mylist):
    sorted_list = []
    for i in mylist:
        posfound = 0 #defaults to 0
        for j in range(len(sorted_list)):
            if sorted_list[j] > i:
                sorted_list.insert(j, i) #put the number in before element 'j'
                posfound = 1 #if you found the correct position in the list set to 1
                break
        if posfound == 0: #if you can't find a place in the list
            sorted_list.append(i) #put number at the end of the list
    return sorted_list
```

Here's a slightly improved version that uses an `else` clause on the loop instead of the `posfound` flag; it also uses slice assignment to do the insertion.

```
def insertion_sort(mylist):
    sorted_list = []
    for i in mylist:
        for j in range(len(sorted_list)):
            if sorted_list[j] > i:
                sorted_list[j:j] = [i]
                break
        else: #if you can't find a place in the list
            sorted_list.append(i) #put number at the end of the list
    return sorted_list
```

Finally, a version that uses `enumerate` to get the indices and items in `sorted_list` rather than a simple `range` loop.

```
def insertion_sort(mylist):
    sorted_list = []
    for u in mylist:
        for j, v in enumerate(sorted_list):
            if v > u:
                sorted_list[j:j] = [u]
                break
        else: #if you can't find a place in the list
            sorted_list.append(u) #put number at the end of the list
    return sorted_list
```

Answer (score 1):

As often, it was a off-by-one error, the code below is fixed. I also made some parts a bit prettier.

```
def insertion_sort(mylist):
    sorted_list = []
    for i in mylist:
        for index, j in enumerate(sorted_list):
            if j > i:
                sorted_list.insert(index, i) #put the number in before element 'j'
                break
        else:
            sorted_list.append(i) #put number at the end of the list
    return sorted_list
```